# Cursor not visible first time escape is pressed but all subsequent times it is

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to learning C# so I'm trying to figure out little bits at a time. Today's task is to have my cursor appear and disappear as I open a panel. I know that unity is weird and you have to build your project to see the cursor changes. However, on said build, when I press escape my panel appears but my cursor doesn't. If I close and reopen the panel the cursor will show up and then everything works as it should.

Something in my code that is causing this or is it just a unity bug?

Also, since I am new to this, any advice is appreciated. Thank you for your time!

```
public class MenuManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pauseMenu;
    public bool gamePause = false;
    bool cursorHide = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        UpdateCursor();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            cursorHide = !cursorHide;
            UpdateCursor();
            PauseMenuOpen();
        }
    }

    private void PauseMenuOpen()
    {
        if (!gamePause)
        {
            pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
            gamePause = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
            gamePause = false;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCursor()
    {
        Cursor.visible = !cursorHide;
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: In general instead of having two individual bools I would align the behavior and use only one single bool flag and make menu and cursor depend on it the same time - which is the behavior you want anyway

Comment: Thank you! Makes more sense to do that. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. it'll work

```
private bool isCursorHide;
private void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
       CursorToggler();
}
private void CursorToggler(){
  if(isCursorHide){
        isCursorHide =!isCursorHide;
        Cursor.visible = isCursorHide;
  }
  else{
     isCursorHide =!isCursorHide;
        Cursor.visible = isCursorHide;
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this different to what OP has? Except that yours is more redundant ....